# Regex to extract whole numbers and ignore number letter combinations

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
ID: 26bc76f7dbe507f9b5fb232748e52b51 To: 17135917389\n
```

I need to pull out the `17135917389` and ignore everything else.

How can I ignore the numbers in `26bc76f7dbe507f9b5fb232748e52b51`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\b\d+\b
```

matches only a whole number. See this [tutorial about word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#To:\D*(\d+)#
```

[Example](http://xrg.es/#1goe500)